# AS3: Saving a sprite to a file and reading it back?

Tags: actionscript-3, file, serialization, sprite, displayobject

I'm using Actionscript 3 and I need to be able to write a vector graphic sprite to a file and then load it back later.  Normally I'd just serialize it in a ByteArray, but apparently you can't serialize a sprite.  But it's just data, so there's got to be some way of representing it in a file.  I've Googled until my fingers are sore, but I can't seem to turn up anything.  Does anyone know how this can be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, the only way to save it as bytearray is to save as an image and also load into bitmapdata later, but then it will not be a sprite anymore. I suggest you somehow convert it to svg and back, if your sprite is/contains "regular" shapes like circles, rects, lines and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I can't do ByteArray.  It's got to be vector, in and out.  I'm actually using as3svgrendererlib to load the original art from SVG, but it's too slow for the end-user.  Which is why I'm looking for a way to store the sprites it gives me in a more native format.

Comment: how about saving your object heierarchy, styles and properties in your own xml format ?   ex   <rect styles="background:#000; border:...." x="".... />

Comment: I've been thinking along those lines.  There's the IGraphicsData structure that holds a series of drawing methods, which then then all be drawn at once with drawGraphicsData.  If I can dig into the SVG library, I should be able to modify it to output that.  Which I could hopefully then serialize.  But that's a lot of work...  I'll see how it goes.

Comment: Indeed, it is a lot of work. You could also create custom shapes, like UIRect, UITriangle, UICircle... and so on. All can be Sprites and have a method that will export they "styles" and "properties" as svg. All you have to do then is to loop them and save the svg.